# Notifying ObservableBuffer listeners on content's member change

Tags: scala, events, javafx, scalafx

I have an `ObservableBuffer[T]` that contains a number of elements and `ComboBox[T]` which displays these elements most likely using it's `toString()` method.

Class `T` (for now let's assume it is mutable) has a `name` field which is changed during execution of the program.

However (obviously) this doesn't trigger the `ComboBox`'s reloading of the elements and that's a requirement.

Only way around this, that I found is through immutability - deleting the given element from the collection and adding the updated one:

```
/* Context */
val items: ObservableBuffer[T]
val beforeChange: T

val afterChange: T = beforeChange.changed
items -= beforeChange
items += afterChange
```

This solution works and immutability is always a good thing so I might go ahead with it, but still curious whether this approach is the only viable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use immutable items, you could try to construct an observable list using [javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableList(List list,                                                Callback extractor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-). Then use the `extractor` to notify about the changes to mutable elements. See also [Combobox refresh value and listview when object content change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896290/combobox-refresh-value-and-listview-when-object-content-change).